# How to use loop for 14 based number system to calculate the sum and product of user input?

Tags: java, for-loop, numbers

I'm in a heap of trouble here, I'm trying to figure out the code for an assignment. What my professor is asking of us is to find the sum and product of two 14 based number 0-9, and A, J, Q, and K by user input.

So far I have code to scan the user input, but I am stuck on the for loop part. I was trying to scan each integer and use the algorithm (value = symbol * 14^(digit-1)) in a for loop, then add all the number. I don't even know where to start with the product of the two.

> An alien species uses 14-based numbering system. Their ten digits, 0 >through 9, are the same as our
>   decimal system. They use A, J, Q and K to represent decimal 10, 11, 12 and 13, respectively. They
>   hire you to write a Java program to do the summation of their two numbers.
>   The program should prompt users for two 14-based numbers and then display the summation and the
>   product of those two entered 14-based numbers. The outputs should also be 14-based. (They are
>   unwilling to learn our decimal systems!) For example, if inputs are 17 and 96, their sum and product
>   should be AK and 1020, respectively.
>
> User interface specifications:
>
> Input:
>
> The program prompts users for two 14-based numbers.
>
> ▪ A 14-based number is a string that contains a combination of digit characters and
>   letter characters of A, J, Q and K, case insensitive.
>
> ▪ Your program should direct users to input the two numbers, separated by
>   space(s), on the same line.
>
> ▪ The data input line is immediately below the prompt message line. In
>   other words, after the prompt message is displayed, your program should
>   force users to enter the two numbers on a new line immediately below
>   the prompt message.
>
> ▪ Your program has to check the validity of input numbers. You can assume input
>   numbers neither are negative nor contain a decimal point.
>   o An example of the input session is illustrated as below:
>   Please enter two 14-based numbers on next line
>   17 96
>
> Output:
>
> o Two 14-based numbers that are sum and product of the two input 14-based numbers.

Those are the instructions, I hope you can help me out on this loop problem, thank you.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class H6_Ruby{
   public static final int A = 10;
   public static final int J = 11;
   public static final int Q = 12;
   public static final int K = 13;
   public static void main(String[] args){
      Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Please enter 2 14-based numbers seperated by a space: ");
      // for digit 1
      String based1 = scan.next();
      int basedDig1 = based1.length();
      int powerDigit1 = basedDig1 - 1;
      for (i = basedDig1[-1]; i  
      //for digit 2
      String based2 = scan.next();
      int basedDig2 = based2.length();
      int powerDigit2 = basedDig2 -1; //unfinished, stuck











   }
}
```

Comment: You don't appear to need a loop. What did you have in mind?

Comment: I was trying to implement a loop because my professor said that the objective of this was to practice loops, so I'm currently trying to figure how that would be accomplished, what I had in mind was looping through each single number(char) and  multiplying that by 14 and the digit place it's in. If that makes sense

Comment: In that case, I suggest you add a loop to iterate over the array. There are millions (literally) of examples of how to use an array. What are you having trouble with?

Comment: replace `J`, `Q`, and `K` with `B`, `C`, `D` and use `Integer.parseInt(str, 14)`.

Comment: for example, 17 should equal 21 on a 14 based number system, correct? I want to loop through the number 17, so that: 7 = 7 because it's in the ones place and then 1 = 14 because it's in the 10th place of the 14-based number system.

Comment: 7+14=21, then I need to find what 96 is on a 14-based sytem and add those together

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should convert those alien numbers to decimals. To do so, just google how to convert numbers from one numeric system to other. Then perform arithmetic operations and convert result back. Seems this is a working implementation (try yourself first :) )

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter 2 14-based numbers separated by a space: ");

    String inputString = scan.nextLine();
    String[] operands = inputString.split(" ");

    int humanizedFirst = getHuman(operands[0]);
    int humanizedSecond = getHuman(operands[1]);

    System.out.println("Sum = " + getAlien(humanizedFirst + humanizedSecond));
    System.out.println("Product = " + getAlien(humanizedFirst * humanizedSecond));
}

private static int getHuman(String alienOperand) {
    char[] chars = alienOperand.toCharArray();
    int result = 0;
    int length = chars.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        int part;
        switch (chars[i]) {
            case 'A':
                part = 10;
                break;
            case 'J':
                part = 11;
                break;
            case 'Q':
                part = 12;
                break;
            case 'K':
                part = 13;
                break;
            default:
                part = chars[i] - 48;
        }
        result += part * Math.pow(14, length - i - 1);
    }
    return result;
}

private static String getAlien(int humanOperand) {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

    while (humanOperand > 0) {
        int digit = humanOperand % 14;
        switch (digit) {
            case 10:
                result.insert(0, 'A');
                break;
            case 11:
                result.insert(0, 'J');
                break;
            case 12:
                result.insert(0, 'Q');
                break;
            case 13:
                result.insert(0, 'K');
                break;
            default:
                result.insert(0, digit);
        }
        humanOperand -= digit;
        humanOperand /= 14;
    }

    return result.toString();
}
```

}